# BUILD FAILED: C:\Users\USER\.ssh\known_hosts (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: ant, scp, jsch

I am trying to automate the deployment process through Ant build XML file. My Ant is of version 1.9.4. As part of that I am trying to send the built war file on to the remote Tomcat server. So, I am using the below code of SCP task.

```
<target name="scp_task">
    <scp file="antproject1.war" todir="${username}@${ipaddress}:${tomcat.webapps.dir}" password="${password}"/>
</target>
```

Along with that I have `ant-jsch-1.9.4.jar` in my `ANT_HOME/lib` directory. And when I am trying to run the Ant command in Windows DOS command prompt. When run the command `ant scp_task`, I am getting the message as

> BUILD FAILED:  C:\Users\USER.ssh\known_hosts (The system cannot find the file specified)

Please help what else should I have to add for the code so that I could deploy my war file perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create the `known_hosts` file in the given path with a public host key of the remote server.

The file uses a common OpenSSH format like:

```
example.com,93.184.216.34 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==
```

---

You can also skip the host key validation, but only if you *do not care about security* (like if you are connecting within a private network).

```
<scp trust="true" .../>
```

See [SCP Task documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html).

Comment: Thank you Martin, I am able to deploy now perfectly but what if the remote machine or the tomcat server is a windows machine. It would not have the 22 port enabled. So, in that case what must be my command/code/task. Actually my environment is in windows only. Please suggest.

Comment: Fine no issues. I shall follow your suggestion immediately. Please respond as it is urgent for me. Thank you.